# Projective planes in higher dimensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

I am fascinated with the idea that just like how lines are equivalent in Euclidean plane ,all conic sections are equivalent in Projective plane. Can this be generalised? That is, is their any plane wherein all surfaces or manifolds of a particular type are equivalent but in lower dimensions they are all completely different like how conic sections are all distinct in Euclidean plane?
I am just a beginner but I would like to understand this idea better.So thanks in advance.